# Facing issue with Tridion Object Caching with Tomcat Java DXA 1.4

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java

We are facing issue with Tridion Object Caching on Web 8.1.0 with Java DXA 1.4 on Tomcat.

When we are enabling Tridion Object Caching in Session and Deployer service and also installed CCS to invalidated content. Everything works well.

But when we restart tomcat then application down and it throws below error:

> 14:34:09.060 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /loadPage.html
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at java.util.TreeMap.rotateLeft(TreeMap.java:2220) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.TreeMap.fixAfterInsertion(TreeMap.java:2287) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:582) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.client.versions.ContentVersionManager.isCompatible(ContentVersionManager.java:107) ~[content-client-api-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getEntityFromDataStore(ContentClient.java:223) ~[content-client-api-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClient.getEntity(ContentClient.java:164) ~[content-client-api-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.web.api.dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.getPublicationMapping(DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.java:27) ~[content-dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.getPublicationMapping(DynamicMappingsRetriever.java:28) ~[content-compatible-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.getPublicationMappingData(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:23) ~[dxa-web8-provider-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver.java:61) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.LocalizationResolverInterceptor.preHandle(LocalizationResolverInterceptor.java:78) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.36]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

With Same set of services with Caching Enabled, everything works fine with .Net DXA 1.4

Please help!!!

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Updated Stacktrace..